# Make Java app reload its config file while running

Tags: java, configuration-files, uberjar

Consider a Java standalone uberjar, which acts as a HTTP server and is run as a Linux service. Some of its functionality depends on an external config file, which might change once in while.

I try to avoid restarting the app every time the config changes. How could this be properly done? I immediately thought of sending a SIGHUP. Could this be caught by java app? Or maybe there is another way to achieve this?

Comment: What you want to do is not totally clear... You can monitor file in java for changes (with the WatchService API, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html), but the java code will only be notified that the configuration file has changed. Reloading the configuration, closing the old HTTP port and opening a new one (for example), or whatever the configuration changes implies, must be a part of the application code, that should explicitly be developped for handling configuration changes at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the configuration file is accessible on the local file system, and the location is known, why not use the Watch Service?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Answer (score 0):

I would use HTTP for sending the command to reload the config file. This will require introducing a special HTTP request (for example, a custom header `X-Uberjar-Reload-Config` that will trigger the operation when used with the root URI). I would set the value of that header to the MD5 or SHA1 hash of the config file, so that the reloading is performed only if the submitted hash sum matches that of the config file.